# Finding the mass of a region given a density function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I know that this involves multiple integrals and that density = mass / volume but I'm not sure how to set up the integrand given this information.

Comment: You just need to integrate the density over the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like $\text{Volume}=\iiint 1dV$, we have $\text{Weight}=\iiint\text{density}\,dV$. In fact, the volume calculation is a special case of the weight calculation: If the density is $1$, then the volume is the weight.

Comment: So this can only be done through triple integration? I'm currently studying for an exam and I've only learned up to double integration so maybe this is not something I should be studying for right now?

Comment: @krauser126 Triple integrals isn't anything more than double integrals. You have an integral whose integrand is an integral. Nesting it one more level doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Ahhh interesting. Doesn't seem too much more complex than double integrals. I think I managed to solve it. I got an answer of M = 6.5

Comment: @krauser126 That looks like the right answer.